# Content-Type of soap call using spring-integration

Tags: http, soap, http-headers, spring-integration, content-type

I'm trying to execute a soapcall using spring-integration. The WSDL is soap 1.2.

My spring configuration:

```
<int:channel id="inputChannel" />

<int:channel id="outputChannel" />

<int:header-enricher input-channel="inputChannel" output-channel="outputChannel">               
    <int:header name="#{T(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders).CONTENT_TYPE}" value="text/xml" />
</int:header-enricher>

<bean id="eduflexWsTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate"
    p:marshaller-ref="eduflexMarshaller" 
    p:unmarshaller-ref="eduflexMarshaller" 
    p:defaultUri="http://srv-nl-edu65/wsParalax/"
    p:messageFactory-ref="soap12MessageFactory"
/>  

<bean id="soap12MessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Java code:

```
MyRequestXml request = new MyRequestXml();
    //construct request

    MyResponse response = (MyResponse) m_template.marshalSendAndReceive(request, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {

        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
            SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) message;
            soapMessage.setSoapAction("soapAction");
        }
    });
```

Initialy the soap action was not set and I got errors about that, so I fixed that by using a WebServiceMessageCallback.

But now I get an error about the content type:

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Unsupported Media Type [415]
```

I'm trying to override it using the spring integration header-enricher, but in wireshark I see that the header content-type is still Multipart/Related.

So my question is how can I force spring integration to set the content type to text/xml? Forcing soap to version 1.2 does not seem to have effect either.

Comment: The question is: why don't use Spring Integration WS Channel Adapters: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ws.html?  With that you don't need to set the `Content-Type` manually. And your code in the question isn't clear. We see `<header-enricher>`, but it isn't clear who is subscribed to that `outputChannel`...

Answer (score 0):

I found out my problem, I had a Jaxb2Marshaller with mtomEnabled set to true.